# Analysing and calculating new values in list of lists in Python3

Tags: python, list, updating

Well, I will try to explain myself correctly:

I am working with python3 with a list of lists in the structure:

```
[[position, color, counts],...]
```

The results are ordered firstly by the color and after by position.

I need to combine the counts and the mean of positions if they have the same color and the position between them being at most +-2.

A brief test example of input would be:

```
[ [1, "red", 3],  [2, "red", 2],  [3, "red", 3], [5, "red", 1], [3, "green", 9],  [10, "green", 4] ]
```

And the ouput expected:

```
[ [2.75, "red", 9], [3, "green", 9], [10, "green", 4]
```

I specially have problems with cases like the 5 "red" 1, due to if a I work performing the mean the distance could be increased falling out the iteration but I want to have it considered as it is at 2 positions of the previous one...

Any idea to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got your problem right. This snippet should work, but it might be optimizable:

```
colors = [ [1, "red", 3], [2, "red", 2], [3, "red", 3], [5, "red", 1], [3, "green", 9], [10, "green", 4] ]

def avg(list): 
    return sum(list) / float(len(list))

def process(colors, threshold=2): 
    colors_combined = {}
    colors_processed = []

    # sort colors by their name
    for color in colors: 
        position, color_name, count = color

        if color_name not in colors_combined.keys(): 
            colors_combined[color_name] = []

        colors_combined[color_name].append([position, count])

    # print colors_combined

    # process the data
    for color in colors_combined.keys(): 
        data = colors_combined[color]

        if len(data) == 1: # there can't be a case, where len(data) = 0
            colors_processed.append([data[0], color, data[1]])
        else: # more than 1 positions to check
            last_position = data[0][0]
            positions = [last_position]
            count_combined = data[0][1]

            for element in data[1:]: 
                if abs(last_position - element[0]) <= threshold: # element is inside of the distance
                    positions.append(element[0])
                    count_combined += element[1]
                else: 
                    colors_processed.append([avg(positions), color, count_combined])
                    positions = [element[0]]
                    count_combined = element[1]

                last_position = element[0]

            if len(positions) > 0: # the last processed elements where inside the distance, but not added
                colors_processed.append([avg(positions), color, count_combined])

    return colors_processed

print process(colors)
```

The output looks like this:

```
[[3.0, 'green', 9], [10.0, 'green', 4], [2.75, 'red', 9]]
```

If you need sorted results, you can add a color ordering instead of `colors_combined.keys()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working approach:

```
list = [ [1, "red", 3], [2, "red", 2], [3, "red", 3], [5, "red", 1], [3, "green", 9], [10, "green", 4], [5, "green", 7], [2, "blue", 3], [4, "blue", 7] ]
color = list[0][1]
result_list = []

sum1, sum2 = 0, 0
count = 0
avg = 0

for item in list:
    if color != item[1]:
        avg = float(sum1)/float(count)
        result_list.append([avg, color, sum2])
        count = 1
        color = item[1]
        sum1, sum2 = item[0], item[2]
    else:
        count += 1
        sum1 += item[0]
        sum2 += item[2]

avg = float(sum1)/float(count)
result_list.append([avg, color, sum2])

print result_list
```

And a [Fiddle](http://pythonfiddle.com/stackoverflow)